Top of HTML webpage being cut off (unable to scroll up far enough) as new lines are added to the bottom
I am making a clone of the NYT game Wordle in Python and HTML (using Flask as the webserver infrastructure if that's relevant) for a high-school level cybersecurity-focused summer camp. For context, the game is intended to show the strength of more complex passwords by allowing the students to guess the passwords in a somewhat game-like format, hence my choice of Wordle as the base or example. For more context, ChatGPT has helped me with the bulk of the program, particularly the HTML formatting and Flask integration. I know the basics of Python from college, so I can look at and make changes to most of the Python backend of this program with very little confusion if any. I know very little of the details of HTML so that is where I needed AI's help.
In my Wordle clone, I don't intend there to be a maximum number of attempts; I want the students to keep working through the game until they find the right answer. Therefore, the program creates a new row of Wordle-styled feedback (green for correct characters, yellow for misplaced, red for incorrect, and purple for correctly placed but wrong case) for each guess the user inputs. However, after too many incorrect guesses, the top of the program (including the first [#] of incorrect guesses) begin to be cut off; the user is unable to scroll up far enough to reach the top. I have not had any issues with cutoff on the sides or bottom, just the top.
ChatGPT suggested and tried implementing an anchor tag, but that didn't solve the problem at all. It caused the program to automatically try to scroll to the top when the correct answer was inputted. While this is very good, it didn't solve the issue; if too many incorrect guesses had been submitted, the top of the webpage was still inaccessible.
I have tried doing some of my own research into HTML with what I've learned from working on this to find what can be done, but I have not had any success in finding an answer. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wordle Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .game-container {
            text-align: center;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 600px; /* Adjust maximum width as needed */
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #f8f9fa; /* Light gray background */
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Soft shadow */
        }
        h1, p {
            font-size: 2em; /* Larger title and text */
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Space below title and text */
        }
        .guess-input {
            width: 45px; /* Adjust width for larger text boxes */
            height: 45px; /* Adjust height for larger text boxes */
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 10px;
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding for larger text boxes */
            font-size: 1.5em; /* Adjust font size for larger text boxes */
        }
        .feedback-container {
            margin-top: 20px; /* Space above feedback */
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .feedback-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Space between feedback rows */
        }
        .feedback-box {
            width: 45px; /* Same width as guess-input */
            height: 45px; /* Same height as guess-input */
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 5px; /* Adjust margin for spacing */
            font-size: 1.5em; /* Same font size as guess-input */
            line-height: 45px; /* Center vertically */
            border-radius: 5px; /* Rounded corners */
            border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Light gray border */
        }
        .feedback-box.correct {
            background-color: #28a745; /* Green background for correct feedback */
        }
        .feedback-box.misplaced {
            background-color: #ffc107; /* Yellow background for misplaced feedback */
        }
        .feedback-box.casewrong {
            background-color: #6f42c1; /* Purple background for casewrong feedback */
        }
        .feedback-box.incorrect {
            background-color: #dc3545; /* Red background for incorrect feedback */
        }
        .submit-button {
            margin-top: 20px; /* Space above button */
            font-size: 1.5em; /* Larger button text */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game-container">
        <a id="top"></a> <!-- Anchor tag for scrolling to top of game message section -->
        <h1>Wordle Game</h1>
        <p id="game-message">
            Guess the password!
            The password contains 
            {{ lowercase_count }} lowercase {{ 'letter' if lowercase_count == 1 else 'letters' }},
            {{ uppercase_count }} uppercase {{ 'letter' if uppercase_count == 1 else 'letters' }},
            {{ number_count }} {{ 'number' if number_count == 1 else 'numbers' }},
            and {{ symbol_count }} {{ 'symbol' if symbol_count == 1 else 'symbols' }}.
        </p>

        <div id="game-feedback" class="feedback-container">
            <!-- Feedback will be displayed here -->
        </div>

        <form id="guessForm">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                {% for i in range(secret_word|length) %}
                    <div class="form-group col-auto">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control guess-input" name="guess{{ i }}" maxlength="1" required>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-auto">
                    <button type="button" id="submitGuess" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit Guess</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitGuess');
            var form = document.getElementById('guessForm');

            submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var formData = new FormData(form);

                var guessArray = [];
                formData.forEach(function(value, key) {
                    guessArray.push(value);
                });

                fetch('/guess', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ guess: guessArray.join('') })
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    displayFeedback(data.guess, data.feedback);
                    if (data.correct) {
                        document.getElementById('game-message').innerText = 'Congratulations! You guessed correctly!';
                        document.getElementById('guessForm').style.display = 'none';
                        scrollToElement('top'); // Scroll to top of game message section
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
            });

            function displayFeedback(guess, feedback) {
                var feedbackRow = document.createElement('div');
                feedbackRow.className = 'feedback-row';

                for (var i = 0; i < feedback.length; i++) {
                    var feedbackClass = '';
                    if (feedback[i] === 'correct') {
                        feedbackClass = 'correct';
                    } else if (feedback[i] === 'misplaced') {
                        feedbackClass = 'misplaced';
                    } else if (feedback[i] === 'casewrong') {
                        feedbackClass = 'casewrong';
                    } else {
                        feedbackClass = 'incorrect';
                    }

                    var feedbackBox = document.createElement('div');
                    feedbackBox.className = 'feedback-box ' + feedbackClass;
                    feedbackBox.innerText = guess[i];
                    feedbackRow.appendChild(feedbackBox);
                }

                document.getElementById('game-feedback').appendChild(feedbackRow);

                // Clear guess inputs after feedback display
                var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.guess-input');
                inputs.forEach(function(input) {
                    input.value = '';
                });

                // Move focus to the first input
                inputs[0].focus();
            }

            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.guess-input');

            inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
                input.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    // Move to next input if there's value and not last input
                    if (input.value && index < inputs.length - 1) {
                        inputs[index + 1].focus();
                    }
                });

                input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
                        // Clear current input and move to previous input if not first input
                        if (input.value === '') {
                            if (index > 0) {
                                inputs[index - 1].focus();
                            }
                        } else {
                            input.value = '';
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            function scrollToElement(elementId) {
                var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
                if (element) {
                    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Please add the relevant parts of your HTML template/rendered HTML (be sure that is a minimal reproducible example) - otherwise people won't be able to help you.
